# How to have a local html file make XHR Cross-domain requests in firefox 17?

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, local

How do you make XHR cross-domain request in firefox 17+ from a local html file?

- [netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead")](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=667312#c3)
  has been removed
- [SpecialPowers.createSystemXHR()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpecialPowers#SpecialPowers.createSystemXHR%28%29) doesn't seem to work

I know an [extension would work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523563/making-crossdomain-ajax-requests-with-addons-for-firefox), but I'd rather not have to "add" anything to firefox unless its necessary.

Comment: Does it has to be Firefox? Chrome has an option --allow-file-access-from-files. Just start chrome from commandline with this option.

Comment: Chrome is fine, but I'd like to find a work-around on Firefox too. This used to be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. You need to toggle [security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy) to false by in "about:config". It [affects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file%3a_URIs) "anything that does same-origin checks, including XMLHttpRequest, XSLT, and XBL."

This also allows reading of local files to a certain extent, so it may cause security issues.

Comment: Thanks so much! I had set this once, but after an automatic update the value got reverted to `true` and I couldn't remember the name of the setting to check. This is very helpful when building websites that use jQuery inclusions for recurring chunks of HTML (headers, footers, etc). Eventually these will get converted to PHP `include`, but I'd rather not have to set up a test server for that sole purpose. In short: this feature is useful, and I appreciate that your answer helped me re-enable it.